# Minimize number of math operation of a specific matrix vector multiplication?

Tags: matrix

Let's say we have a Matrix M and a column vector v like below

[image]

multiply

[image]

equals

[image]

Assume we can only perform multiplication, addition and substraction operation.
With normal approach we need 3 multipliction and 3 addition to calculate `row1`
`row1 = v_1 + 2v_2 + 2v_3 + 4v_4`.
However we can do it smartly by

```
t1 = v_1 + 2*v_3
t2 = v_2 + 2*v_4
row1 = t1 + 2 * t2
row2 = t2 - t1
row3 = ...
```

Totally we only need 4 multiplication and 5 addition/substraction to do the calculation.

Is there any algorithm or approach to figure out the minimum number of operations?

P.S. I know sub-expression elimination algorithm can be used for this kind of problem.
However I am trying to figure out whether it can be solve by linear algebra method or explaination.

Comment: This is very specific for the matrix you have. Is that really what you want? You'd have to find the optimal solution for every new matrix.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth , that matrix is only an example. consider matrix all M has small constant integers.